# DPKG: can't upgrade due to syntax error in trigger file

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I was just trying to ugrade/update and I ran into some issues due to unmet dependancies:

```
anonymous@anonymous:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9-host : Depends: libbind9-160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
              Depends: libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
              Depends: libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
              Depends: libisccfg160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
              Depends: liblwres160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
 dnsutils : Depends: libbind9-160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: libdns1100 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: libisc169 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: libisccfg160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: liblwres160 (= 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) but 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So some issue with bind9 depending on version 1.1 but I have 1.0 installed. So I try fix-broken:

```
anonymous@anonymous:~$ sudo apt-get  --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
```

# Bunch of packages no longer required

```
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbind9-160 libdns1100 libirs160 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 liblwres160
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libbind9-160 libdns1100 libirs160 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 liblwres160
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 251 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,349 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error: syntax error in file triggers file '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Hmmm.... so not so useful. If I try auto-remove, I get the first error message. Here's the content of the trigger file mentioned by dpkg:

```
  GNU nano 2.9.3                 /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File                           

/.
/etc
/etc/gnome
/etc/gnome/defaults.list
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/desktop-file-install
/usr/bin/desktop-file-validate
/usr/bin/update-desktop-database
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/desktop-file-utils
/usr/share/doc/desktop-file-utils/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/desktop-file-utils/README
/usr/share/doc/desktop-file-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/desktop-file-utils/copyright
/usr/share/emacs
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/desktop-entry-mode.el
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/desktop-file-utils
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/desktop-file-install.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/desktop-file-validate.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/update-desktop-database.1.gz
/usr/bin/desktop-file-edit
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/man/man1/desktop-file-edit.1.gz
```

Comment: That looks more like a filelist file (maybe `/var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.list`?) than a triggers file - did the original file get overwritten perhaps?

Comment: The one you mentioned has similar content indeed, but only a few entries. What does a trigger file is supposed to look like? Could I restore it to some default template?

Answer (score 0):

One option: I renamed the trigger file in question (so it wouldn't be found by dpkg). I then re-ran upgrade, auto-remove etc.

This seems to have worked, in the sense that I could proceed with upgrades. However I would still like to know what my trigger file is supposed to look like and how/if I can restore it in some ways...

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have still security.ubuntu.com rows in your sources.list

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

bind9 has security update at 1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1 but only available through security.ubuntu.com . I found out mine repositories were disabled by one script or another.